# gazebo crash when I roslaunch pr2_empty_world

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just installed ubuntu 12.04 and ROS fuerte.
When I run 'roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_empty_world.launch'
the entire pr2 model is not showed up on screen.

I only installed ROS and PR2 simulator package.
Is there anybody helps me?

The terminal shows following messages:

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/scripts/spawner", line 161, in 
if **name** == '**main**': main()
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/scripts/spawner", line 139, in main resp = load_controller(name)
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 432, in **call** return self.call(*args, **kwds)
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 522, in call raise ServiceException("transport error completing service call: %s"%(str(e))) rospy.service.ServiceException: transport error completing service call: unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details

[WARN] [WallTime: 1346191217.658283] [0.089000] Spawner couldn't reach pr2_controller_manager to take down controllers.

[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 23235, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gazebo -u /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/dpark/.ros/log/bb7462a6-f15b-11e1-acc1-38607740c1c2/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/dpark/.ros/log/bb7462a6-f15b-11e1-acc1-38607740c1c2/gazebo-2*.log

[spawn_pr2_model-4] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/dpark/.ros/log/bb7462a6-f15b-11e1-acc1-38607740c1c2/spawn_pr2_model-4*.log

[default_controllers_spawner-24] process has died [pid 24562, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/scripts/spawner --wait-for=/calibrated base_controller base_odometry head_traj_controller laser_tilt_controller torso_controller r_gripper_controller l_gripper_controller r_arm_controller l_arm_controller __name:=default_controllers_spawner __log:=/home/dpark/.ros/log/bb7462a6-f15b-11e1-acc1-38607740c1c2/default_controllers_spawner-24.log].

log file: /home/dpark/.ros/log/bb7462a6-f15b-11e1-acc1-38607740c1c2/default_controllers_spawner-24*.log

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42512/gazebo-crash-when-i-roslaunch-pr2_empty_world/) by [dpark](https://answers.ros.org/users/3101/dpark/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-08-28**:
Can you do
"unset OGRE_RESOURCE_PATH"
and try again?  If gazebo still crashes, can you do
"roslaunch gazebo_worlds debug.launch"
then type "bt" at the gdb prompt after crashing:
"(gdb) bt"
and post all outputs?  thanks.

**Comment by [dpark](https://answers.ros.org/users/3101/dpark/) on 2012-08-29**:
I did "unset OGRE_RESOURCE_PATH". Still it crashes. I also did "roslaunch gazebo_worlds debug.launch". It was not crash. The crash is only happen when I launch pr2 things~ Any suggestions? Thanks

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-08-29**:
Hi, I am trying to make debugging process easier, can you take a look at this page (http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Troubleshooting) and fill in some more details as mentioned by the second half of the wiki here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This question is almost a year old, but I still wanted to add my answer].

I also noticed this happening with

```
roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_empty_world.launch
```

which spawns the PR2 itself, so I tried spawning it myself in an empty world after reducing the solver step size and voilà!

So, while I guess it's not recommended to alter the file I'm about to mention, my solution is nonetheless, the following:

```
rosed gazebo_worlds empty.world
```

and change

```
<dt>0.001</dt>
```

to something like

```
<dt>0.0001</dt>
```

And then, whenever you launch the simulator, you just wait until everything has loaded and just set back the step size to whichever you prefer.

---

Originally posted by [RayR](https://answers.ros.org/users/4566/rayr/) with karma: 16 on 2013-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I encountered the same problem and i solved by  killing the server and client first and launch again

```
killall gzclient

killall gzserver
```

---

Originally posted by [ljk](https://answers.ros.org/users/5470/ljk/) with karma: 155 on 2013-11-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hillripper21](https://answers.ros.org/users/36849/hillripper21/) on 2020-07-20**:
2020 and this is the only thing that fixed my issue. Thank you